# Using sapply and tapply

Tags: r

I struggle to correct my code.  Given this data frame

```
S <- data.frame(Z1=c("A","A","A","D","D","A","A","A"),
                Z2=c("A","A","A","D","D","C","C","D"),
                K1=c(24,36,44,63,34,26,19,23),
                K2=c(12,24,13,16,23,25,12,34))
```

I applied this transformation:

```
B <- sapply(1:2, function(x) {
    x1 <- S[c(x, x+2)]
    tapply(x1[,2], x1[,1], FUN=function(S) ceiling(median(S)))
})
colnames(B) <- c("G1","G2")
```

which I expected to set `B` to

```
       G1   G2
C       0   19
B       0    0
A      25   13
D      49   23
```

but instead I get this error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("G1", "G2")) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Comment: I can't tell you how to *fix* this, but I believe at least part of the problem is that the function you're passing to `sapply` doesn't produce vectors that are consistently the same length.

Comment: Can you please explain in words what your function is suppose to do? Your code doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @David, I believe that the codes fully make sense, sorry about that

Comment: FYI you should not be trying to use "code snippets" for this.  They only work for HTML/Javascript questions.  Also, please learn to indent your code properly, it makes it much easier for everyone else to understand.

Comment: If David says he doesn't understand your code you should believe him.  For the record, I have no idea what this is trying to accomplish, either.

Comment: If you have all categories, it does work perfectly. So  Codes make sense actually

Comment: Hmmm... I think I understood what you were trying to do.

Comment: I get that you expect this code to take `S` as shown and produce `B` as shown, and I think I understand why you thought it ought to work, too, but I don't understand *why you want to do that*, or why your data has this form, or whether you realize how brittle the `S[c(x, x+2)]` thing is, or ...

Comment: How does your expected output have a rowname 'B' in it when your original grouping variables don't contain any 'B' values?

Comment: @ Zwol, I do not understand why you do not  understand why we  may have some data.

Comment: Data doesn't just fall out of the sky.  Explain its *structure*.  Explain the meaningless `Zn` and `Kn` and `Gn` colnames and the equally meaningless A, B, C, D values in the Z columns.  Explain what the numbers in the K columns measure.  Explain why there are exactly two each Z and K columns. It's hard to debug something presented as an abstract exercise in logic.

Answer (score 2):

*One* of your problems is that R has no idea you consider `Z1` and `Z2` to be categorical variables that can take values A, B, C, D.  The way you tell it this is with the `factor` type.

```
S <- data.frame(Z1=c("A","A","A","D","D","A","A","A"),
                Z2=c("A","A","A","D","D","C","C","D"),
                K1=c(24,36,44,63,34,26,19,23),
                K2=c(12,24,13,16,23,25,12,34))

S$Z1 <- factor(S$Z1, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
S$Z2 <- factor(S$Z2, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

Notice how I have to explicitly spell out that all four of A, B, C, D are possible even though not all of them appear.  Having done that, your transformation function produces a 2D matrix to which `colnames` can be applied.

```
B <- sapply(1:2, function(x) {
    x1 <- S[c(x, x+2)]
    tapply(x1[,2], x1[,1], FUN=function(S) ceiling(median(S)))
})
colnames(B) <- c("G1","G2")
```

**However,** you don't get zeroes where you expected them to be, you get `NA`s:

```
> B
  G1 G2
A 25 13
B NA NA
C NA 19
D 49 23
```

This is because the median value of an empty set is undefined.  You can paper over that with `is.na`:

```
> B[is.na(B)] <- 0
> B
  G1 G2
A 25 13
B  0  0
C  0 19
D 49 23
```

Also, the `S[c(x, x+2)]` thing is extremely brittle and I would not be relying on it in production code if I were you.  Likewise the thing where you use `sapply(1:2, function(x) ...)` where the function operates on global variables.

You may find the `reshape2` package easier to persuade to do what you want.

Comment: @Zwol- thanks, if you would not rely on it, May I have your codes, if at all possible?

Comment: This is  an issue, especially if you have 20 or more factors. So i do not think the code provided help? Any help?

Comment: if you have 20 or more factors or if you want to use it within a function

Comment: Ask a new question, then.  I have taken you as far as I can here.

Comment: You can generelize this as follows `indx <- 1:20 ; 
S[indx] <- lapply(S[indx], factor, levels = LETTERS[1:4])` (if you want to refactor the first 20 columns for example). Other than that, I don't really understand the logic behind which levels to pick. There was no `B` level in neither of the first two columns, how the function supposed to know that it should be there?